# Safe-args: Passing an object from an imported package. Possible?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel, android-safe-args

I'm trying to pass a Track object from the GPX Parser package that I've imported.

This is my navigation xml:

```
<argument
        android:name="track_to_pass"
        app:argType="io.ticofab.androidgpxparser.parser.domain.Track" />
```

I'm getting runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mypackage.myapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mypackage.myapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

Can I pass it in any way to another fragment?

Comment: Is `Track` a `Parcelable` or `Serializable` class? It would need to be one of those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting runtime exception

There should be much more to the stack trace than that.

> Safe-args: Passing an object from an imported package. Possible?

As Ian notes in a comment, that will only be possible if the class implements
`Parcelable` or `Serializable`. Presently, [`Track` does not](https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser/blob/master/parser/src/main/java/io/ticofab/androidgpxparser/parser/domain/Track.java). You might file a feature request for `Track` and related types to be made `Parcelable`.

Comment: TY, much appreciated. I think I'll just pass an URI and build the logic in the next fragment.